# I'm using Drew Noakes's metadata extractor project. Instead of print the output in console,i want to store them in a .txt file.How can i do that?

Tags: java, metadata-extractor

I'm using Drew Noakes's metadata extractor project.When I run the SampleUsage.java, it gives the output in the console. I need to store them in a .txt file, when i do so, I simply lose some of the information, such as, ICC,IPTC information. How can I store them also?

My code is here:

```
package com.drew.metadata;

import com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader;
import com.drew.imaging.ImageProcessingException;
import com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader;
import com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegProcessingException;
import com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegSegmentMetadataReader;
import com.drew.metadata.exif.ExifReader;
import com.drew.metadata.iptc.IptcReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        File file = new File("Tests/Data/image.jpg");

        try {
            Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);

            print(metadata);
        } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        try {
            Metadata metadata = JpegMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);

            print(metadata);
        } catch (JpegProcessingException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        try {

            Iterable<JpegSegmentMetadataReader> readers = Arrays.asList(new ExifReader(), new IptcReader());

            Metadata metadata = JpegMetadataReader.readMetadata(file, readers);

            print(metadata);
        } catch (JpegProcessingException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    private static void print(Metadata metadata) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("E:/Project/output.txt"));
         //System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

        for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {


            for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {

            output.println(tag);
           //System.out.println(tag);

            }

            if (directory.hasErrors()) {
                for (String error : directory.getErrors()) {
                    System.err.println("ERROR: " + error);
                }
            }
        }
    output.close();
    }
}
```

Sample Image:
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpz6g.jpg)

Received Output:

```
[Exif IFD0] Make - samsung
[Exif IFD0] Model - SM-G360H
[Exif IFD0] X Resolution - 72 dots per inch
[Exif IFD0] Y Resolution - 72 dots per inch
[Exif IFD0] Resolution Unit - Inch
[Exif IFD0] Software - G360HDDU0ANL3
[Exif IFD0] Date/Time - 2016:03:19 14:43:43
[Exif SubIFD] Exposure Time - 1/392 sec
[Exif SubIFD] F-Number - f/2.6
[Exif SubIFD] Exposure Program - Program normal
[Exif SubIFD] ISO Speed Ratings - 50
[Exif SubIFD] Exif Version - 2.20
[Exif SubIFD] Date/Time Original - 2016:03:19 14:43:29
[Exif SubIFD] Date/Time Digitized - 2016:03:19 14:43:29
[Exif SubIFD] Shutter Speed Value - 1/390 sec
[Exif SubIFD] Aperture Value - f/2.6
[Exif SubIFD] Brightness Value - 0
[Exif SubIFD] Exposure Bias Value - 0 EV
[Exif SubIFD] White Balance - Unknown
[Exif SubIFD] Flash - Flash did not fire
[Exif SubIFD] Focal Length - 3.3 mm
[Exif SubIFD] Exposure Mode - Auto exposure
[Exif SubIFD] White Balance Mode - Auto white balance
[Exif SubIFD] Scene Capture Type - Standard
[Exif SubIFD] Contrast - None
[Exif Thumbnail] Compression - JPEG (old-style)
[Exif Thumbnail] X Resolution - 72 dots per inch
[Exif Thumbnail] Y Resolution - 72 dots per inch
[Exif Thumbnail] Resolution Unit - Inch
[Exif Thumbnail] Thumbnail Offset - 589 bytes
[Exif Thumbnail] Thumbnail Length - 15961 bytes
[File] File Name - image.jpg
[File] File Size - 429252 bytes
[File] File Modified Date - Sat Mar 19 17:09:40 +06:00 2016
```

Expected output:

```
[JPEG] Compression Type - Baseline
[JPEG] Data Precision - 8 bits
[JPEG] Image Height - 966 pixels
[JPEG] Image Width - 1288 pixels
[JPEG] Number of Components - 3
[JPEG] Component 1 - Y component: Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 2 horiz/2 vert
[JPEG] Component 2 - Cb component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert
[JPEG] Component 3 - Cr component: Quantization table 1, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert
[Exif IFD0] Make - samsung
[Exif IFD0] Model - SM-G360H
[Exif IFD0] X Resolution - 72 dots per inch
[Exif IFD0] Y Resolution - 72 dots per inch
[Exif IFD0] Resolution Unit - Inch
[Exif IFD0] Software - G360HDDU0ANL3
[Exif IFD0] Date/Time - 2016:03:19 14:43:43
[Exif SubIFD] Exposure Time - 1/392 sec
[Exif SubIFD] F-Number - f/2.6
[Exif SubIFD] Exposure Program - Program normal
[Exif SubIFD] ISO Speed Ratings - 50
[Exif SubIFD] Exif Version - 2.20
[Exif SubIFD] Date/Time Original - 2016:03:19 14:43:29
[Exif SubIFD] Date/Time Digitized - 2016:03:19 14:43:29
[Exif SubIFD] Shutter Speed Value - 1/390 sec
[Exif SubIFD] Aperture Value - f/2.6
[Exif SubIFD] Brightness Value - 0
[Exif SubIFD] Exposure Bias Value - 0 EV
[Exif SubIFD] White Balance - Unknown
[Exif SubIFD] Flash - Flash did not fire
[Exif SubIFD] Focal Length - 3.3 mm
[Exif SubIFD] Exposure Mode - Auto exposure
[Exif SubIFD] White Balance Mode - Auto white balance
[Exif SubIFD] Scene Capture Type - Standard
[Exif SubIFD] Contrast - None
[Exif Thumbnail] Compression - JPEG (old-style)
[Exif Thumbnail] X Resolution - 72 dots per inch
[Exif Thumbnail] Y Resolution - 72 dots per inch
[Exif Thumbnail] Resolution Unit - Inch
[Exif Thumbnail] Thumbnail Offset - 589 bytes
[Exif Thumbnail] Thumbnail Length - 15961 bytes
[ICC Profile] Profile Size - 3144
[ICC Profile] CMM Type - Lino
[ICC Profile] Version - 2.1.0
[ICC Profile] Class - Display Device
[ICC Profile] Color space - RGB 
[ICC Profile] Profile Connection Space - XYZ 
[ICC Profile] Profile Date/Time - 1998:02:09 06:49:00
[ICC Profile] Signature - acsp
[ICC Profile] Primary Platform - Microsoft Corporation
[ICC Profile] Device manufacturer - IEC 
[ICC Profile] Device model - sRGB
[ICC Profile] XYZ values - 0.964 1 0.825
[ICC Profile] Tag Count - 17
[ICC Profile] Copyright - Copyright (c) 1998 Hewlett-Packard Company
[ICC Profile] Profile Description - sRGB IEC61966-2.1
[ICC Profile] Media White Point - (0.9505, 1, 1.0891)
[ICC Profile] Media Black Point - (0, 0, 0)
[ICC Profile] Red Colorant - (0.4361, 0.2225, 0.0139)
[ICC Profile] Green Colorant - (0.3851, 0.7169, 0.0971)
[ICC Profile] Blue Colorant - (0.1431, 0.0606, 0.7141)
[ICC Profile] Device Mfg Description - IEC http://www.iec.ch
[ICC Profile] Device Model Description - IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGB
[ICC Profile] Viewing Conditions Description - Reference Viewing Condition in IEC61966-2.1
[ICC Profile] Viewing Conditions - view (0x76696577): 36 bytes
[ICC Profile] Luminance - (76.0365, 80, 87.1246)
[ICC Profile] Measurement - 1931 2° Observer, Backing (0, 0, 0), Geometry Unknown, Flare 1%, Illuminant D65
[IPTC] Coded Character Set - UTF-8
[IPTC] Enveloped Record Version - 4
[IPTC] Caption/Abstract - 
[IPTC] Keywords - about cse#01;<name>      " emam";<friendof>    "sujon";<place>        "kotbar"i;<about>         "sujon";<friendof>      "emam";<description>   "cvc"
[File] File Name - image.jpg
[File] File Size - 429252 bytes
[File] File Modified Date - Sat Mar 19 17:09:40 +06:00 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to do something like this.

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("E://Project/output.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

Comment: It's not working the way i'm looking,boss.Another suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how the file manipulation works in Java.

```
import java.io.*;
public class CopyFile {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {  
      FileInputStream in = null;
      FileOutputStream out = null;

      try {
         in = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
         out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");

         int c;
         while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
         }
      }finally {
         if (in != null) {
            in.close();
         }
         if (out != null) {
            out.close();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This code is from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your file path looks suspicious. Should it be `"E:/Project/output.txt"`, with only a single forward slash after the colon?

Secondly, you are creating a print stream for each tag. You should create it outside your loop.

```
public static void saveMetadataToFile(File image, File output)
    throws ImageProcessingException, IOException
{
    Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(image);
    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(output);
    try {
        for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
            for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
                printStream.println(tag);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        printStream.close();
    }
}
```

Once you're done with the `PrintStream` be sure to close it so that it gets flushed and any resources are released.

I haven't tested this code, but I think it will help you make progress. You might also like to customise how the tag is presented in your output.

Comment: It gave the output like this:[Exif IFD0] Make - samsung. Thanks for your kind suggestion.Even then,i'm not getting the desired output.Can You suugest another way please? I'm also trying.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what output you are expecting? I have no idea what your desired output looks like.

Comment: for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {

     {
        System.out.println(tag);
          }   When I run this code, u know what output it gives.It prints the output on the console. I just want to store them in a .txt file instead of printing them.Can you get it now,boss?

Comment: The code you pasted here doesn't compile. Where does `tag` come from? I've edited my answer a bit. Please try it again.

Comment: It's working partially.The code looks like:private static void print(Metadata metadata) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
       PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("E:/Project/output.txt"));
 for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
output.println(tag);
                }
  if (directory.hasErrors()) {
   for (String error : directory.getErrors()) {System.err.println("ERROR: " + error);
                }
             }
         }     
    output.close();
    }
Still,all the output fields aren't being stored,sir.

Comment: Sir,the output we're having from the above code is only [Exif IFD0]s,[Exif SubIFD]s,[Exif Thumbnail]s and [File]s information.  I think we're missing JPEG, ICC and IPTC information.The question is, how to recover them also?Thank you for your continuous help.We're very close I think.Just,few more edit can be fruitful.I tried in many ways,couldn't work.Hoping suggestions from you.

Comment: Sounds like the image doesn't have those types of metadata. Test with other images. Not all images have ICC/IPTC/etc.

Comment: But,when the same image is used as the input image,the console output gives the ICC/ IPTC information.Only when they are to be stored on .txt,they are simply lost!!However,you helped a lot.I am so much grateful.Thank you.

Comment: I don't have enough information to help. Please _edit your original question_ and include your full code, a sample image, the output you expect, and the output you receive.

Comment: I've a question. How did, I mean with what software you added the IPTC info in the image, say, 'withExifAndIptc' in the Tests folder, which  in that case is 'communications'. If you don't understand me, then please go to the Tests folder of your project, select the image 'withExifAndIptc', go to properties and then, click details.

Comment: I didn't add the IPTC info. That seems like a different question. The image you attach doesn't contain any metadata (perhaps SO removed it). Regardless, your code is overwriting the output file three times, which might be your bug. I've edited my answer again, and if that doesn't work for you then I'm sure you have some other bug in your code which is not related to the metadata-extractor library.

Comment: It's not working.Where's the 'output' path?It also shows error in print(metadata);

Comment: `saveMetadataToFile(new File("myfile.jpg"), new File("output.txt"));`

Comment: Sir,can you please send the full code?It's so much urgent. I'm just a beginner, and I can't get all the things properly. If you would send me the full code, it would help me a lot. If the code doesn't fit here, can you please mail me in this address?ehossen080@gmail.com.Sorry for continuous disturbing.

Comment: That is the full code. I'm sorry, but I don't know how else to help you.

Comment: Ok. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Can you help me to append another image's metadata? I meant, I want to keep image.jpg's metadata, and after that, anothe image's metadata too in the same .txt file.